# Remove .php extension / .htaccess / Apache2.conf - What should be modified to make it work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to remove the .php extension from my website.

I have this structure: 
/var/www/site/

FYI, in folder site, I have a lot of subfolders.

In site folder, I create .htaccess file.
I inputed these line of code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

After this change the website still require .php extension.
So I tried to modify Apache2.conf and to add:

```
    <Directory /var/www/site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I restarted the server with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that, the website is still requiring the .php extension on localhost.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Is there other solutions?

Comment: You could remove your `.htaccess` file entirely and simply add `MultiViews` to the `Options` declaration in your `Apache2.conf`

Comment: I will take a look at this answer and see if it fixes my issue.

Comment: Options Multiviews is working. Thanks. So why do people use .htaccess to remove the .php extension? It looks more complicated, no?

Comment: Lack of awareness I'd imagine. There's a lot of tutorials and examples for mod-rewrite. `MultiViews` would run in to trouble if you had directories or multiple files with the same base-name too, eg `index.html`, `index.php`, `index.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
# Remove .php extension
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried but this is not working. Thanks.